# Add wordpress 'slug' as category class

Tags: wordpress, class, styles, slug

I want to stylize each of my categories with background colors to make them unique.
How can i do it with a function? tried milion codes, none worked.

Example:
https://fmportugal.net/downloads/rb-versailles

I want fm 2020 to have a color, and Downloads another diferent one, and Novas ligas e expansões too.

maybe the theme was overiding some of my earlier tries.

Comment: edit: Or, make this option a text box, so i can define what class will it have.
Theme is newsphere

https://i.imgur.com/j0qpR3T.png

Comment: Look at custom fields plugin from wordpress and custom post types

Comment: what plugin? can you be more specific?

Comment: found it! really simple trick: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126368/add-multiple-classes-different-style-for-each-category-tag /close